# certbot don`t see response

Tags: docker, nginx, https, certbot

I need to get free SSL cert. by certbot, for this I use certbot docker image.
Bellow is **docker-compose.yml for nginx and certbot**

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - media_volume:/viber_bot
      - etc-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:rw
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - django-network
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - etc-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - media_volume:/viber_bot
    command: certonly --webroot  --webroot-path=/viber_bot -d example.net.ua
    networks:
      - django-network
```

**nginx default.conf **

```
`upstream web {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
    location  /.well-known/acme-challenge{
        alias /viber_bot/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        default_type "text/plain";
}
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;

    }

        autoindex off;
}
`
```

Certbot logs

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority report                                                                                                         ed these problems:
  Domain: example.net.ua
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2001:41d0:b:a74:5:39:10:93: Invalid response from http://example.net.ua/.well-known/acme-challen                                                                                                         ge/wrTOxm_W7JtshDZzGOA7-4CyyMstk5GirLCmFNlfKg0: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"ru-RU\" prefix=\"og: ht                                                                                                         tp://ogp.me/ns#\" class=\"no-js\">\n<head>\n\n    <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#"

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. E                                                                                                         nsure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files c                                                                                                         reated there can be downloaded from the internet.
```

As I understand certbot create file with key in '/viber_bot/.well-known/acme-challnge' and trying to get it for secure reasons. I`ve checked it during test launch and file accessible from internet by correct url.

ask any questions. I`m online. Thank you for help

I`ve tried change ports and nginx conf file. But I`ve no results

Comment: original url was replaced to example.net.ua